# Equivalent to bootstrap's "pull-right" using flexbox?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

If I have a two-column layout, I would use a "pull-right" class (float:right) on the first column to make it display on the right side on desktops, but remain in the first position (top) when the columns are stacked on mobile.

But if I use pull-right on a column that has display:flex, it doesn't pull to the right. It remains on the left:

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap">

   <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right" style="display:flex">
   First Column
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-4">
   Second column
   </div>

</div>
```

How can this be done with flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pull-right` does `float: right` and Flexbox doesn't have that.

Instead use `order: 1`, or [Bootstrap 4's `flex-last`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#flex-order),  which, in this case, will position it *last*.

*Thanks to [ZimSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650942/equivalent-to-bootstraps-pull-right-using-flexbox#comment84300008_48650963), it appears that Bootstrap have reworded `flex-last` to [`order-last`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order).*

- More on their updates here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Stack snippet

```html
<div class="row" style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap">

   <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right" style="display:flex; order: 1">
   First Column
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-4">
   Second column
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As of 4.0.0, the flex ordering classes are now `order-last`, `order-first` and `order-(0-12)`

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I need to brush up on flexbox. Will accept as the answer when it lets me.

Comment: @ZimSystem Thanks, updated...and missed that as I don't use Bootstrap that often.

Comment: @LBF I need brush up on Bootstrap 4... :)

Comment: also better link to the link of class utilities to find these classes ;) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: well and you no more need to link to alpha version, the upgrade is completely done so you can use the standard link :)

Comment: order-last doesn't pull your content to the right of your container element. It just puts it after other elements, which may well be in the left side of the container in case other elements are small enough or missing. It's not equivalent of pull-right.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis That is correct, and to fully do a Flexbox variant, where it does push it to the right, also an auto margin is needed, e.g. `ml-auto`. Also _justify-content_ can be used, and whether which one depends on requirements. Why I showed to use _order_, is that it does what _float_ does, kind of, where it can push an element to the right side of another, even if that element is before in the markup, which is what one want to achieve in this case. For another, e.g. what you described, the one I mentioned here will be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a `pull-right` class that uses a flexbox to position elements on the right side:

```css
.pull-right {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```